# divide two count() of two select in one request

Tags: sql

i have the relationnel schéma:

- Client (code, nom, prenom, localite, num_tel, categorie)
- COMMANDE (num_cmd,  #code,  date_cmd)
- ARTICLE (ref_article,  designation,  prix_ht, TVA)
- LIGNE_CMD (# num_cmd,  #ref_article,  quantite,  remise)

it want to write an sql request :Quel est, pour chaque localite, le nombre moyen de commande par client?

first request:

```
select count(*) 
from client,commande
where client.code=commande.code
group by localite,client;
```

second request:

```
select count(*)
from client,commande
where client.code=commande.code
group by localite;
```

but i don't now how to divise the two request and to correlate the count of client in their localite, someone can guive me a solution to resolvre this request

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions . . . and proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  Then you can use window functions.  Something like this:

```
select client, locality,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as ratio
from client cl join
     commande co
     on cl.code = co.code
group by client, localite;
```

I say "something" because you should also qualify all column references, so it is unambiguous which table they come from.